# CI and SQL Server from Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I’m actually developing a CI app in my developer machine with Windows and XAMPP, using de sqlsrv driver to connect to the MS SQL Server 2008 database.

But the final server machine is an Ubuntu server, and trying to run the app from there doesn’t work because of the sqlsrv driver not installed in the server.

I tried the mssql driver and the app starts to load but it ends with SQL queries errors (SQL queries previously tested and working).

What do you recommend?

Is it possible to connect from Linux/PHP/CI to SQL Server 2008? If there is a way, will it be as fast as running on Windows? It will be compatible with CI Active Record?
Is it better to create a new Windows server?

Thx

Comment: Yes it is possible, with SYBASE-Functions ... see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sybase.php

Comment: donald123, I think it isn't compatible with CI ActiveRecord and I'd have to use ODBC. I will look at it if there isn't a better option, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should develop on whatever you deploy to so if you will stick to dev on windows, deploy to a windows box.

If you do want to get it working, I have seen a ruby app talk to ms sql 2005 before, you need to make sure you have FreeTds working, this looks like a good walkthrough:

http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php

If you are using sql 2008 there are some features which probably are not in sql 2008 like table valued parameters which FreeTds won't support so it might be not working because you are trying to use something it can't do - have a look at the query that fails and see what types it has and the types of the responses, if anything is new to sql 2008 it might not work.